# Launch FTP url in Edge-IE mode from powerbuilder

Tags: internet-explorer, ftp, microsoft-edge, powerbuilder

Can FTP url link accessible in Edge IE mode from powerbuilder application?
I am using powerbuilder 2019 R3.

Need help to open ftp url in browser from powerbuilder.
Note: know that ftp is not supported in microsoft edge, google.

Comment: So Edge doesn't support but running but in IE mode it does?

Comment: An  alternative is  to launch windows/system32/ftp.exe and script the download/upload action,

Comment: Yes it support FTP link in Edge IE mode. @MattBalent

Comment: Hi @keerthana keerthi, does the suggestion below work for you? If you have any other questions, feel free to contact me.

Comment: No, i tried but doesn't work for me...even after IE mode policy configured.@RainaZhao-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to configure IE mode on Edge:

1. Navigate to "**edge://settings/defaultBrowser**" in Edge
2. Set "Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode (IE mode)" option to **Allow**
3. Add your "ftp://" links under "Internet Explorer mode pages" section. they will automatically open in IE mode.
   [image]

Alternatively, you could [Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) to open a page in IE mode.

Then, try to access it from powerbuilder application.

Comment: No, i tried but doesn't work for me...even after IE mode policy configured.

Comment: Hi @keerthana keerthi, you could also report the issue on powerbuilder forum for more help.